# Is there an opposite of the Kronecker Delta?

Tags: functions, kronecker-symbol

Instead of $\delta(n,n) = 1$ and $\delta (n,k) = 0$, is there something that returns $0$ when the arguments are the same, and $1$ when the arguments are different. Is there a special function that does this? Is there a name for it?

Thanks!

Comment: We usually use $(n,k) \rightarrow 1-\delta(n,k)$, and there is no name for it.

Comment: You could call it the complementary delta function....but that isn't something used by many if anyone at all. The numerical software FORM calls it that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; the function $1 - \delta(n,k)$ should work nicely!

Comment: Wow! Very simple. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a name for this though?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: Kronecker atled